# How can I check time in C++?

Tags: c++, time

My goal is to write a program that will do the following:
when the user enters time point in the future, it should display time until that time moment in a format (hh:mm:ss),
if a user asks for time, it should return current time in a format (hh:mm:ss). How do I use system time to achieve my goal?
My current status so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
class Time{
    int hour, minute, second;
public:
    void SetTime(int hour1=0, int minute1=0, int second1=0){
        hour = hour1;
        minute=minute1;
        second=second1;
        cout<<"set time working";
    }
    void display(){
       cout<<"hour | minute | second"<<endl;
       cout<<hour<<" "<<minute<<" "<<second;
    }
};

int main(){
    Time time;
    //char om;
    int hour1, minute1,second1;
    cout<<"enter the hour,minute,second: ";
    cin>>hour1;
    cin>>minute1;
    cin>>second1;
    time.SetTime(hour1,minute1,second1);
    cout<<"\n The current time?";
    time.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The computer is always counting in the background.  It's called the _system clock_.  So, you can just query it when the user sets the time, and then again when they request it.  Compute the difference in seconds, and add that to your own clock routines.  Or use the rest of `<ctime>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use C time function for getting computer clock's time.

The basic idea is following:

- Ask the user for "his" time
- In the same time save the computer's current time

When is time to showing updated current time:

- Check computer current time
- Calculate the users's current time using previous stored times as a delta

To do this, due to how C "time" function works, I've to store in the program the time variables in seconds, so I have to convert hours, minutes and seconds in just one single variable storing seconds.

Here's the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Time {
private:

    time_t userTime;
    time_t computerTime;

public:

    void SetTime(int hour1 = 0, int minute1 = 0, int second1 = 0)
    {
        userTime = hour1 * 60 * 60 + minute1 * 60 + second1; // Convert input time in seconds.
        time(&computerTime); // Get computer's current time.

        cout<<"set time working";
    }

    void display()
    {
        time_t currentComputerTime;
        time(&currentComputerTime); // Get computer's updated current time.

        time_t currentUserTime = userTime + (currentComputerTime - computerTime); // Calculate current user's time in seconds.

        // Convert time_t variable in hours, minutes and seconds.
        int hour   = currentUserTime / (60 * 60);
        int minute = (currentUserTime / 60) % 60; 
        int second = currentUserTime % 60;

        cout<<"hour | minute | second"<<endl;
        cout<<hour<<" "<<minute<<" "<<second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Time time;
    //char om;
    int hour1, minute1,second1;

    cout<<"enter the hour,minute,second: ";
    cin>>hour1;
    cin>>minute1;
    cin>>second1;

    time.SetTime(hour1,minute1,second1);

    char pcz[200];

    cout<<"\n The current time?";
    cin >> pcz;

    time.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you just explain whats going on in the program

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you cheat slightly. At the start, right before or after the user enters the time, you obtain the system clock value. Then you wait for user to ask for time. When he asks, obtain the system clock value again, subtract from it the previous value — that will give you the amount of time passed. Add this amount to the time the user entered, and show the result.